# if (dis)proving a conjecture on graph theory can be done just by a counter example then can every (dis)proof be mapped actually to a counter-example?

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques, undecidability

Suppose we have a conjecture on graph theory that can be (dis)proved by means of a counter example, then, is it true that every alternative (dis)proof of the conjecture can be mapped to a counter example?

This is in the general case, but for instance, can any proof that the hadwiger's conjecture is false be mapped to a counter example, i.e., a particular graph?

Or,

Can any proof about a purported property $P(L)$ of a language $L$, susceptible of being (dis)proved by a counter example, be mapped to a particular word, say $w$ meaning $w$ a counter example, i.e., $P(L):=FALSE\;$  since $w$ exists?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it seems you're asking if every false graph property has a counterexample. Obviously this is true: by definition there must be some graph for which the property doesn't hold. On the other hand, a proof that the property doesn't hold for all graphs may not necessarily give an example of such a graph; this is called a *non-constructive* proof.

Comment: Indeed. It would be nice if we would have a simple example of such a property to illustrate it.

Comment: ok, for instance, suppose you want to disproof that "every planar graph with at least 100 vertexes has a triangle.  Could you prove this without necessarily give a way to construct a counter example? I.e. a proof that can't be used to create a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Stephen's last remark, a classic non-constructive proof (though not about graphs) is the conjecture

> For every two irrational numbers $r, s$ the value of $r^s$ is irrational.

This is not true; a proof by contradiction looks like this:

Let $r=s=\sqrt2$. Then $r^s=\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is either rational or not.

- If $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is rational, we have a counterexample to the conjecture.
- If, on the other hand, we have that $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is irrational, then $(\sqrt2^\sqrt2)^\sqrt2$ is an irrational number raised to an irrational power, but $(\sqrt2^\sqrt2)^\sqrt2=\sqrt2^2=2$ is rational, again contradicting the conjecture.

In other words, we've found two irrationals $r, s$ for which $r^s$ is rational, even though this proof doesn't tell us which two they are. (In fact, by the [Gelfond/Schneider Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), $\sqrt2^\sqrt2$ is transcendental, hence irrational, but we didn't need that here.)